# Why doesn't fast-scan cyclic voltammetry work with metal electrodes?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

Every paper I've seen discussing it uses it with carbon nanofiber or some other carbon material like a diamond. If the physical principles by which it works are based on sweeping through voltages, I don't understand why it can't be used with metal electrodes.

I've tried to search through the literature but I haven't come across any clear answers.

Answer (score 2):

It actually does work. Carbon fiber electrodes are just more useful for the neuro work that fast scans are popular for these days.

Here is an example from the literature of a metal electrode used up to $3*10^6$ V/s , [Amatore et. al. JEAC](http://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0728(00)00131-5)